# dpkg completely broken? It does not recognize root

Tags: dpkg

When I install a package as `root`:

```
Setting up grub-pc (1.99-21ubuntu3.17) ...
/usr/bin/ucf: line 341: test: !=: unary operator expected
/usr/bin/ucf: line 630: test: =: unary operator expected
ucf: Not loading confmodule, since we are not running as root.
/usr/bin/ucfr: line 241: test: !=: unary operator expected
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Similar things happens. In short, it does know I'm running with `root`, that's totally weird.

Does dpkg use fakeroot or something? Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, the `id` command was replaced with something empty.

Reinstalled coreutils and the problem is gone.